# Linux epoll syscall, waiting though data available

Tags: python, c, linux, system-calls, epoll

Testing Linux syscall **epoll** using a simple parent-child program.

**Expected behaviour**

As the child writes a no every second, the parent should read it from the pipe and write a no every second to stdout.

**Actual behaviour**

The parent waits till the child writes all the nos, and then reads all data from pipe and writes to stdout. Verified by doing strace on parent. It blocks in epoll_wait.

[please check README in github more information](https://github.com/tuxuday5/Samples)

**Parent**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define NAMED_FIFO "aFifo"

static void set_nonblocking(int fd) {
  int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
  if (flags == -1) {
    perror("fcntl()");
    return;
  }
  if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
    perror("fcntl()");
  }
}

void errExit(char *msg) {
  perror(msg);
  exit(-1);
}

void printArgs(char **argv,char **env) {
  for(int i=0;argv[i];i++)
    printf("argv[%d]=%s\n",i,argv[i]);

  for(int i=0;env[i];i++)
    printf("env[%d]=%s\n",i,env[i]);
}

void PrintNos(short int max,char *name) {
  int fifo_fd,rVal;
  int bSize=2;
  char buffer[bSize];

  fifo_fd = open(NAMED_FIFO,O_RDONLY);
  if(fifo_fd<0)
    errExit("open");

  for(short int i=0;i<max;i++) {
    rVal = read(fifo_fd,buffer,bSize);
    if(rVal != bSize)
      errExit("read");
    printf("%03d\n",i);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[],char *env[]) {
  //int pipe_fds_child_stdin[2] ;
  int pipe_fds_child_stdout[2] ;
  pid_t child_id ;

  //if( pipe(pipe_fds_child_stdin) < 0 )
  //  errExit("pipe");

  if( pipe(pipe_fds_child_stdout) < 0 )
    errExit("pipe");

  child_id = fork();

  if( child_id > 0 ) {
    const int MAX_POLL_FDS = 2;
    const int BUF_SIZE = 4;

    size_t readSize;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int status;

    int epoll_fd;
    int nfds ;
    struct epoll_event e_e, e_events[MAX_POLL_FDS];

    memset(e_events,'\0',sizeof(e_events));
    memset(&e_e,'\0',sizeof(e_e));
    //close(pipe_fds_child_stdin[0]);
    close(pipe_fds_child_stdout[1]);

    epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);
    if(epoll_fd < 0)
      errExit("epoll_create1");

    e_e.data.fd = pipe_fds_child_stdout[0];
    e_e.events  = EPOLLIN;

    if(epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, pipe_fds_child_stdout[0], &e_e) < 0)
      errExit("epoll_ctl");

    while(1) {
      nfds = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, e_events,MAX_POLL_FDS,-1);
      if( nfds < 0)
        errExit("epoll_wait");

      for(int i=0;i<nfds;i++) {
        if( e_events[i].data.fd == pipe_fds_child_stdout[0]) {
          if( e_events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
            readSize = read(pipe_fds_child_stdout[0],buf,BUF_SIZE);
            if( readSize == BUF_SIZE ) {
              write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,BUF_SIZE);
            } else if(readSize == 0) { // eof
              errExit("readSize=0");
            } else {
              errExit("read");
            }
          } else if( e_events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) {
            printf("got EPOLLHUP on pipefd\n");
            wait(&status);
            exit(0);
          } else {
            errExit("Unexpected event flag returned by epoll_wait on waited fd");
          }
        } else  {
          errExit("epoll_wait returned non-awaited fd");
        }
      }
    }
  } else if( child_id == 0 ) {
    close(0);
    close(1);
    //close(pipe_fds_child_stdin[1]);
    close(pipe_fds_child_stdout[0]);

    //dup2(pipe_fds_child_stdin[0],0);
    dup2(pipe_fds_child_stdout[1],1);

    execvpe(argv[1],&(argv[1]),env);
    //PrintNos(100,"P");
    //errExit("execvp");
  } else {
    errExit("fork");
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
import sys
import time
import os
#f=open("aFifo",'r')
for x in range(10):
    #try:
    #    val = f.read(2)
    #except Exception as e:
    #    raise 
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'{x:03d}')
```

Comment: You seem to have removed the earlier instance of this question and created a new one. That's not helpful. In stead you should have asked a *specific question*. So far there is none.

Comment: @KlausD. SO provides provision to delete a question, which I did and posted a new question. Not sure how it is not helpful. The fact that you seen this post, validates my reasoning.

Comment: SO also provides a function to edit a question which is the preferable way to do it.

Comment: `epoll()` is not a good choice for reading from a pipe as the only response will be when the write end of the pipe is closed.

Comment: @user3629249 thx. please provide documentation which supports your claim

Comment: @KlausD. Exactly my point. How do you know your approach is right and mine not? As long as the question is understandable, approach doesn't matter.

Comment: you might want to read this SO question [epoll via pipe with child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375047/communication-with-child-process-using-pipes-and-epoll)

Comment: @user3629249 that is different problem all-together. Questioner was using **execl** , whereas he intended to use **execlp** .

Comment: The referenced question shows how to properly use `epoll()`  Which is why I referenced it.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to python buffering, which can be disabled by passing -u option to python.

---

After much searching and research, understood that this is due to pipe buffer. Though the client writes, it is in pipe buffer. Only after the pipe buffer is full, the kernel sends ready event on that descriptor. The minimum is pagesize, kernel doesn't allow to set below that. But it can be increased. Got to this, by changing from epoll to poll/select. After changing to poll/select the behaviour was same. Blocking though data was available in pipe.

```
import fcntl
import os

F_SETPIPE_SZ=1031
fds = os.pipe()
for i in range(5):
    print(fcntl.fcntl(fds[0],F_SETPIPE_SZ,64))


$ python3.7 pipePageSize.py 
4096
4096
```

This is the modified client. Appropriate changes in server too.

```
import time

pageSize=1024*8

for x in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(f'{x:-{pageSize}d}')
```

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. The problem is due to application level buffering, not any kernel restrictions.  You need to flush the Python stream, not to increase amount of data written. The latter would be a crazy waste of electrons.

Comment: @n.m. Hate to say, but you are right! **python -u** fixed the issue.